# Return value from callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I have value inside callback function and couldn't return successfully.

```
async pos(convertedCodeDBSearch) {
    var dd;
    const x =  await idealPostcodes.lookupAddress(convertedCodeDBSearch, function (error, searchResults)  {
      return searchResults.result.hits[1];
    });
    console.log('x', x);
  }
```

I need to return `searchResults.result.hits[1];` from function.
Here is the code,
Thank you.

Comment: Is the console log not printing what you expect or is pos not returning what you expect? Its hard for us to know what is going on without seeing the lookupAddresses code.

Comment: You can't do these kind of stuff, you'll need to keep coding inside the callback. Just put the console log into the callback and change the variable names.

Comment: Before the line with the `return`, add `console.log(searchResults)` to see what you got. Furthermore, the callback function is an error-first function and you should add a check first to see if an error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you are using [this npm package](https://github.com/ideal-postcodes/ideal-postcodes-node) or a fork of it. If this is the case, you should revise your logic, because the call to `lookupAddress` does not return a value by itself, meaning that the `x` in your code will always be `undefined`.

Since you are already working with async functions, my suggestion is using the Node helper [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilpromisifyoriginal) to extract the result from the callback function into a promise. This promise can be awaited to get the success value of the original callback (here `searchResults`).

```js
const { promisify } = require('util');

async pos(convertedCodeDBSearch) {
    var dd;
    const searchResults = await promisify(idealPostcodes.lookupAddress.bind(idealPostcodes))(convertedCodeDBSearch);
    return searchResults.result.hits[1];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it'll solve you're problem, but why don't you get rid of the callback entirely and utilize the async/await syntax to it's fullest?

```
async pos(convertedCodeDBSearch) {
    var dd;
    try {
        const x =  await idealPostcodes.lookupAddress(convertedCodeDBSearch);
        const results = x.result.hits[1];
        console.log(`The results are: ${results}`);
        return results;
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("Something went wrong")
    }
}
```